# Android Popup Window Dismiss issue

Tags: android

I am trying a sample of popup window and facing 2 issues
1) The popup is not closing
2) showAtLocation is giving null pointer exception.

```
public void onShowPopup(View v){
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainActivity);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.informationpopup, relativeLayout);

    final PopupWindow popWindow = new PopupWindow(getBaseContext());
    popWindow.setContentView(inflatedView);

    popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popWindow.setFocusable(true);
    //popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);


    //popWindow.showAtLocation(inflatedView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

    // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
    Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Close", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            popWindow.dismiss();        
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you inflate is wrong. Also showAtLocation  view should be the parent view to show the popup.

Here you go, this should work....

```
   public void onShowPopup(View v){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.informationpopup, null,false);

    final PopupWindow popWindow = new PopupWindow(getBaseContext());
    popWindow.setContentView(inflatedView);

    popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
    Button close = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Close", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
            popWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popWindow.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popWindow.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, v.getLeft(),v.getBottom());
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! This did work. I see you have made couple of adjustments to the code. Could you please explain. My understanding was that we need to inflate to a given View and not to NULL. Also why is the change needed on the OnClickListener ? The following blog on inflate says not to use null [link]http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/